# How to use awk for multiple character delimiter?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a log file with lines like :

```
Insert request received from system 1
Modify request received from system 2
```

I want to get the text after "received from" from the log. The equivalent grep and cut command would be (if it supported multiple character delimiter)

```
grep "received from" mylogfile.log | cut -d"received from" -f1
```

How can I recreate this with `awk`

Comment: Please read the awk man page, the information you're asking about is right there.

Comment: Can you ever have lines in your input that don't have `received from` in them? If so, [edit] your question to include some such lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FS` can be a string or regular expression in `awk`.

```
awk -F' received from ' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' mylogfile.log
```

You could also use `sed` to delete everything up to `received from`:

```
sed -n 's/.*received from //p' mylogfile.log
```

Comment: Left no meat on the bone here.... Well done.

Comment: No need to test the same regexp twice - `awk -F' received from ' 'NF>1{print $2}'` and `sed -n 's/.*received from //p'`

Comment: I was thinking that `NF==1` when the line starts or ends with the delimiter, but forgot that empty fields are only suppressed when using the default whitespace delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You might do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Insert request received from system 1
Modify request received from system 2
```

then

```
awk 'sub(/.*received from /,"")' file.txt
```

gives output

```
system 1
system 2
```

Explanation: I use [`sub` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) with 2 arguments: regular expression and empty string, so it does alter current line in-place and return 1 if change made else 0, this value is then used for selection - only lines when change was made are printed. **Warning**: this solution assumes each line has at most 1 `received from` , if this does not hold true *rightmost* one is treated as delimiter.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

You could set the field separator to  `received from`  and then print the second field if it is there:

```
awk -F' received from ' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' mylogfile.log
```

Or using split and check if there is a second field:

```
awk '{
  n = split($0,a," received from ")
  if (n > 1) print a[2]
}' mylogfile.log
```

Output

```
system 1
system 2
```

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> mawk NF=NF OFS='' FS='^.+ received from '
> ```

```
system 1
system 2
```